# How to creat a new Hive session in HUE(and clean the temporary table)?

Tags: hive, hql, hue

Each time we open one hive/beeline cli we can get one session.

In HUE, I create one temporary table, when I close the HUE web UI, and login again, the temporary table is also exist.

I found that temporary table is being with one Hive session.

But we can't call the api or close the connection.

I search the HiveQL manual, I have no idea how to make it.

Answer (score 2):

In Hue 3.10, you can click in 'Sessions' icon in the editor and close it.